Is there a way to auto-pad with spaces using column mode in VSCode (like Notepad++)
In Notepad++, you can Alt-LeftClick to select a vertical insert point over a series of lines, and then start typing.  When doing so, Notepad++ will automatically insert as many spaces as it needs to on each line to pad up to your insertion point before inserting the typed characters.
Is there a way to do this in VSCode?
I work on a legacy code base where the "blame" number is required to be placed at column 73 on each line.  e.g.:
From this:
IIF NOT RAINNG  $
  THEN                            
    PLAYFB      $
  ELSE  '' If it is raining ''    
    PLAYBG      $
  ENDIF   '' IIF NOT RAINNG ''    

to this:
IIF NOT RAINNG  $                 ''If it's not raining             ''111111
  THEN                                                                111111
    PLAYFB      $                 ''  Go play football              ''111111
  ELSE                            ''If it is raining                ''111111
    PLAYBG      $                 ''  Play a board game             ''111111
  ENDIF   '' IIF NOT RAINNG ''                                        111111

So it's a drag to have to manually put in spaces or tabs to get to the correct column on every line.  Notepad++ made this simple, but I'm trying to switch over to VSCode because of its superior capabilities and extensibility.
Note, this is not a duplicate of Can I make VSCode column mode like Notepadd++?.
